# multiplying binomials with $e^x$ being one of the terms

Tags: calculus

If I have the problem:

$$(5x^3+e^x)(5+e^x)$$

i use FOIL to get:

$$25x^3+5x^3e^x+5e^x+(e^x)^2$$

is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thanks You!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. And $(e^x)^2 = e^{2x}$.  So it looks pretty.

Answer (score 1):

**Tip:** Write $a=5x^3; b=e^x; c=5; d=e^x$. Now you have $$(a+b)(c+d)$$ and we know that $(a+b)(c+d) = ac+ac+bc+bd$. Now put the values back in and group the results: $$5x^3e^x+25x^3+5e^x+e^{2x}$$